# Excessive UL margin in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, html-lists, margin, html-rendering

In my html, I have a generated `ul` element that hold `li`'s with `img`'s in them.

I get a strange `3px` (approx) excesive margin between my `li`'s in addition to css defined margin.

Here is a Chrome debug console snapshot. A excessive area is outlined with red:

[image: strangeMargin]

A `ul`s style is the following:

[image: excessiveMarginULStyle]

`li`'s style is:

[image: excessiveMarginLIStyle]

Exactly the same excessive margin appears in Firefox.

Why is it there? How do I get rid of it?

Comment: This seems like a bug. The margin is removed when using HTML5 drag as well [(As seen in this article)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25520904/html5-reorder-the-children-li-of-ul-by-drag-and-drop-the-borders-between-li-el/25525846#25525846) which leads to some weird flinching if not removed.

Answer (score 2):

Solved. It's how browsers render line breaks between li's. Had to force the html generator render all li's in one line to remove the space between.