# HTML5: Reorder the children li of ul by drag and drop, the borders between li elements are missed

Tags: javascript, css, html

The original list as below:
[image: Normal]

After drag and drop, the pic as below:
[image: Error]

The item 1 and item 2 are connected, how to fix this issue?
My intent is to reorder the list items by drag and drop. Thanks in advance.
Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>example</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        .main-area {
            margin-left: 10%;
            margin-right: 10%;
            min-width: 600px;
        }

        ul {
            padding-left: 0;
            text-align:center;
        }

        li {
            word-break: break-all;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 400px;
            height: 200px;
            margin-bottom: 3px;
            border-radius: 3px;
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        // on source element
        function dragstart (ev) {
            ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
            ev.dataTransfer.setData("srcId", ev.currentTarget.id);
            ev.dataTransfer.setDragImage(ev.currentTarget, 0, 0);
        }
        function dragend(ev) {
            ev.dataTransfer.clearData("srcId");
        }

        // on target element
        function dragover(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
        }
        function drop(ev) {
            var srcId = ev.dataTransfer.getData("srcId");
            var srcObj = document.getElementById(srcId)
            if(srcObj != ev.currentTarget){
                var list = document.getElementById('list')
                list.insertBefore(srcObj, ev.currentTarget);
            }
        }
    </script>
    <div id='main-area'>
        <ul id='list'>
            <li id='1' draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart(event)" ondragend="dragend(event)" ondragover="dragover(event)" ondrop="drop(event)">
                111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
            </li>
            <li id='2' draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart(event)" ondragend="dragend(event)" ondragover="dragover(event)" ondrop="drop(event)">
                222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
            </li>
            <li id='3' draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart(event)" ondragend="dragend(event)" ondragover="dragover(event)" ondrop="drop(event)">
                333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
            </li>
            <li id='4' draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart(event)" ondragend="dragend(event)" ondragover="dragover(event)" ondrop="drop(event)">
                444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Run the html file with Chrome.

Comment: Try creating a livedemo like http://liveweave.com/WG7nlu

Comment: Resize the browser window to make two items in a row, then drag and drop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing linebreaks between li's will prevent the behavior.

[**Demo**](http://liveweave.com/GspV7H)

It's really weird and seems like a bug to me. [Here's a similar article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754294/excessive-ul-margin-in-chrome-and-firefox)

Comment: If add the li elements with JS dynamically, how to remove the linebreaks?

Comment: Update your question with the code you use to create the HTML and i will have a look.

Comment: Seems No linebreaks generated when add the li dynamically. http://liveweave.com/sZVz5s